# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS only runs with AMD Radeon HD6490 and not Intel HD 3000

Tags: 12.04, ati, graphics, intel-graphics, hp

I'm a bit new to Ubuntu 12.04. I have used it for a few months now, but I don't exactly know the commands for Ubuntu.

Also I have been searching for a solution to my problem with my HP ProBook 4730s (with Hybrid Graphics).
But there is no case or thread opened with my current problem.
All people want to use both of the GPU's, but I don't care about the fatass AMD card.

I am not planning on gaming on my Ubuntu, it's pure for my education and learning some knowledge about other OSes than Windows.

The only thing I want:
I want to use the Intel HD Graphics GPU so that my laptop has a little more time on a single charge. Now, I'm using the AMD card, because there's no driver for the Intel. I'm getting maybe an hour out of my machine if it runs on Ubuntu and gets incredibly hot on the palmrest, keyboard, underside of the laptop and I can't hold my hand in front of the fangrill.

Can somebody explain me how I could easily install the Intel GPU on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?
Please no talk about all those codes, I really don't get much of it.

I'm ready to give you all the anwsers to help me get my solution.

Small system specs for now, because i have a empty accu and forgot my charger :P

HP ProBook 4730s
Intel Core i5 2450M with Intel HD Graphics 3000
8GB 1333 DDR3 RAM (2x4GB)
AMD Radeon HD6490 1GB
17,3 Inch LED Panel
1x Intel 330 Series SSD 180GB Sata 6GB/s
1x Crucial C300 Series SSD 256GB Sata 6Gb/s
No optical drive

By the way:
If I use a hardware program (forgot the name and can't look right now), I can see that my AMD GPU is connected to the Intel Host Controller. If I look closer, there is a address assigned to it. Both the Intel and the AMD GPU have a address (ofcourse).
The AMD card is number 1 on the Host controller and my Intel GPU is the second on the Host controller. Could that have to do something to do with it?

I'll check this thread every day, even every hour if I must.

If you see lacky English, I'm sorry, but I'm Dutch :P

For the HP ProBook specs:

[HP Driver download page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=nl&cc=nl&prodNameId=5060895&taskId=135&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5060893&lang=nl&cc=nl)

[HP Quickspecs page (4330s, 4430s and 4530s combo page](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13948_div/13948_div.HTML)

With kind regarts

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Lenovo y580 with HD Intel 4000.  I simply removed the nvidia drivers and the computer booted into unity just fine.  Perhaps try that (you could always reinstall them if it doesn't work.)